# UIPageViewController not loading page content after accessing UITableView content

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, delegates, uipageviewcontroller

This is likely a noob question about the PageViewControllers or general management of my views.

I have a PageViewController that allows me to swipe through... well, you know what it does.  On each of these dynamic pages, I have a label that gives a current game status message and an embedded UITableView that has a list of players and their scores (see attached #1).

When I tap on the player to see their profile, and then return back to my pageviewcontroller the data I see is the data that had when I initially left the view -- which is good.  However... when I then swipe forward or back to the subsequent pages, that data does not clear itself out and gets layered on top of the newly swiped in view (see attached #2).  Also, the tableview should be showing no points for this screen.

The 3rd screen grab shows how the data *should* look.

Thoughts / comments, look familiar to anyone?

thanks in advance
:-)

[image: Initial page prior looking at their profile]
[image: combined views with data not clearing]
[image: How the second page should look]

**EDIT**

*Added more details by request*

The number 2, "..." and "player 1 is in the lead" parts are all UILabels found on the PageContentViewController shown in the example below.  My ScoringViewController is really only responsible for setting up the page views, and loading the subsequent pages.

**ScoringViewController.m**

```
-(void)loadPages:(int)startingPage {
    // Create page view controller
    self.pageViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageViewController"];
    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;

    PageContentViewController *startingViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:startingPage];
    NSArray *viewControllers = @[startingViewController];

    // Advance to next page ("hole");
    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

    // Change the size of page view controller
    self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(
                                                0,
                                                0,
                                                self.view.frame.size.width,
                                                self.view.frame.size.height);

    [self addChildViewController:_pageViewController];
    [self.view insertSubview:_pageViewController.view atIndex:0];
    [self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}

-(PageContentViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index { 
    // Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
    PageContentViewController *pageContentViewController = [self.storyboard
                                                        instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageContentViewController"];

    pageContentViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageContentViewController"];
    pageContentViewController.pageIndex = index;

    return pageContentViewController;
}
```

**PageContentViewController.m**

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // Add 1 to the page index since it's zero based.
    int tmpPageIndex = _pageIndex + 1;

    _lblCurrentHole.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",tmpPageIndex];
}
```

In my configureCell method for the table view, it's just hitting a leaderCheck function and then displaying the proper message.  Beyond that, nothing else really.  It works great if I *don't* go to the profile page and come back.

The code has it's roots in an example I found on AppCoda awhile back. (http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/).

**EDIT**
Including a close up of the content view with colors to show the separation of the main view on top and the tableview on the on the bottom.

Is something just not clearing from memory properly when I leave this view and come back to it?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you show the code/storyboard details.  It **looks** like you might be adding a label to the view each time it is presented.  But I can't tell from the pics whether that's a "content page" view, or a table view cell, or ...

Comment: Are those labels in a tableView cell, or directly in a page content view?

Comment: Labels are in a page content view.  The TableView only has the names / scores of the players.  I'll add some color to the views to separate them out visually a little better.

Comment: Thanks, really helpful images.  From where is `loadPages:` called.  Could it be called twice?

Comment: Good question.  I see it's only being called one time... and it's located in ViewWillAppear:
    
    `if ( (_currentHole == _currentHoleIndex) || _currentHoleIndex == 0) {
    [self loadPages:nil]; } else { [self loadPages:_currentHole];
    }`

Comment: I think that may be part of your problem - the ScoringViewController's viewWillAppear will be called when it is first displayed, but also when the profile view controller is dismissed.  Hence you end up with two pageViewControllers, with (possibly) one showing through the other.  Does it work if that code is in `viewDidLoad` instead?

Comment: Oooh... good question.  I'm rocking on another project at the moment but will be able to get back to it in about an hour-ish.  I'll give it a shot.. thanks for the suggestion, I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks @pbasdf... that was it.  Not sure why I moved it out of viewDidLoad and into viewDidAppear.  I had it in there at one point as I pulled an old copy out of Git from a week or two back before I added the profile page.  Weird.  I up-voted your comment, but wasn't able to give you credits for the Answer.  If you want the points, submit an answer and I'll mark it as the accepted answer.  thanks again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `loadPages:` method in the `ScoringViewController` is being called twice, because it is called from `viewWillAppear`.  The `viewWillAppear` will be called when the VC is first displayed, but also when the profile view controller is dismissed. Hence you end up with two `pageViewControllers`, with one showing through the other. It should work OK if you move that code to `viewDidLoad` instead.